# How to use a collection of partials to insert partials based on the url?

Tags: partials, docpad, eco

I'm using docpad with the eco templating engine and the partials plugin. The point of this is to insert a list of snippets into a landing page.

The logical approach (to me) is to iterate through a collection of the snippets and insert each snippet.

I have the following structure (following the [beginner guide on adding blog posts](http://docpad.org/docs/begin#adding-the-blog-posts) and the [partials doco](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-partials#partials-plugin-for-docpad)):

```
src
├── documents
│   ├── index.html.eco
│   ├── scripts ...
│   └── styles ...
├── files...
├── layouts
│   └── default.html.eco
└── partials
    ├── hello.html.eco
    └── world.html.eco
```

Contents of hello.html.eco:

```
---
title: "Hello"
isArticle: true
---
Hello
```

Contents of world.html.eco:

```
---
title: "World"
isArticle: true
---
World
```

Contents of default.html.eco (the layout)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Partials</title>
    <%- @getBlock("styles").add(["/styles/style.css"]).toHTML() %>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%= @document.title %></h1>
    <%- @content %>
    <%- @getBlock("scripts").add(["/vendor/jquery.js","/scripts/script.js"]).toHTML() %>
</body>
</html>
```

And the contents of index.html.eco:

```
---
title: "Welcome"
layout: "default"
isPage: true
---
<p>Welcome to my website</p>

<% for page in @getCollection("partials").findAllLive({isArticle:true}).toJSON(): %>
<article>
    <%- @partial("<%= page.url %>") %>
</article>
<% end %>
```

As is above, docpad will crash with a `Cannot read property '0' of null`. However if I remove the line `<%- @partial("<%= page.url %>") %>` then it works.

The following line retrieves all the files in the partials directory where isArticle is set to true.

```
<% for page in @getCollection("partials").findAllLive({isArticle:true}).toJSON(): %>
```

If I change `<%- @partial("<%= page.url %>") %>` to `<p>page.url</p>` then the output lists /hello.html and /world.html, which is what I expect.

It appears that using `<%-` twice in one line, effectively attempting to embed some eco, is causing the problem.

Does anyone know how I can get around this? I'm trying to avoid manually coding a `@partial("<filename>")` for each file that I wish to be inserted. Is there a way to somehow pass to `@partial` the value of `page.url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not to do with the partial plugin, it's because of the second `<%=` statement. As we're already in eco, we don't need to escape back into eco again. So the second `<%=` is redundant as variables can be referenced directly.

I should have originally titled this question "How do you reference variables in eco that have been previously set".

The solution is to use the following for index.html.eco:

```
---
title: "Welcome"
layout: "default"
isPage: true
---
<p>Welcome to my website</p>

<% for page in @getCollection("partials").findAllLive({isArticle:true}).toJSON(): %>
<article>
    <%- @partial(page.url) %>
</article>
<% end %>
```

As can be seen above, `page.url` is now referenced directly.